# No line numbers on exceptions from assembly generated by CompileAssemblyFromSource

Tags: .net, debugging, scripting

My application has a scripting feature where I compile an in-memory assembly from the user's script using CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource. It's similar to what's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614186/dynamically-generate-modules-in-same-assembly-space/622360#622360).

It works very well, but any exceptions that get thrown from the script code don't have line numbers in the stack trace. I tried setting the compilerParameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true, but it still doesn't include line numbers.

Is it possible to get line numbers on exceptions from an in-memory assembly?

Here are the key pieces of code I'm using to compile the assembly:

```
        CompilerParameters compilerParameters =
            compilerInfo.CreateDefaultCompilerParameters();
        compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        compilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        compilerParameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;

        ...

        CodeDomProvider codeProvider = compilerInfo.CreateProvider();
        CompilerResults compilerResults =
            codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
                compilerParameters,
                new string[] { sourceCode });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We worked around this by writing the source out to a temporary file and then using that file to compile the code rather than an in-memory string. This provided us with meaningful debug information that we otherwise couldn't get.

Comment: I guess it's a trade off between the hassle of managing and cleaning up the temp files with the benefit of debug info.

Comment: @Don: Exactly. We tried to do it without temp files, but we tried in vane. However, the tidy-up was not working for us depending on when the files were released so, as we create the files in the user's temp directory, we left it predominantly for the user to clean-up.

Comment: Yep - that's what we did too.

Answer (score 2):

From comments I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306891/assembly-not-loading-for-asp-net-web-application/307040#307040) and [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/NETscripting/Oct2005/post23953297.asp), it looks like the PDB file for the assembly has to be in the same directory as the assembly before the line numbers will be attached. It seems like this rules out debugging info for in-memory assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

In an application developed for .NET Framework 4, I do get line numbers in the exception stack traces when the system I am running on has .NET Framework 4.5 (or presumably later) installed, but I do not get them when it only has .NET Framework 4 (Full or Client Profile).

So yes, it is possible to get line numbers on exceptions from an in-memory assembly now, namely by running on .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: What u like to describe here?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @shivam I have edited the answer to add a clarification. Is it clearer now that I _do_ answer the question (with a new answer that didn’t exist yet at the time it was asked) and am _not_ critiquing or requesting clarification?